# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.getAnnotation

Tags: java, spring

when I run my junit test I can get right result and the data can be stored into database.

when I deploy my project into tomcat, I got this exception.

my spring version is 3.1.1 and tomcat version is 6.0.

```
2012-02-29-16:40:54,968 ERROR   - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.getAnnotation(Ljava/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1399)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1500)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:670)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doPut(ManagerServlet.java:435)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:640)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

it does not work ):

pom.xml:

```
<properties>
        <spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>3.6.9.Final</hibernate.version>
        <jdbc.driver.groupId>mysql</jdbc.driver.groupId>
        <jdbc.driver.artifactId>mysql-connector-java</jdbc.driver.artifactId>
        <jdbc.driver.version>5.1.13</jdbc.driver.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- spring tx -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- asm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SPRING end -->

        <!-- jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- LOGGING begin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- LOGGING end -->





        <!-- PERSISTENCE begin -->
        <!-- hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.15.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- PERSISTENCE end -->

        <!-- dbcp connection pool -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- spring orm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- jdbc driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${jdbc.driver.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>${jdbc.driver.artifactId}</artifactId>
            <version>${jdbc.driver.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Give us dependency:tree and also do you have any lib registered on your tomcat/jdk (lib/ext etc) and check in your system classpath you don't have any wrong version of spring

Comment: related question/solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164001/spring-transaction-manager-annotionat-style-runtime-error-in-glassfish3

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The correct signature is

```
public static <A extends Annotation> A getAnnotation(Method method,
                                                 Class<A> annotationType)
```

but *something* tries to call

```
public static <A extends Annotation> A getAnnotation(AnnotatedElement element,
                                                 Class<A> annotationType)
```

The second method was introduced with <strike>[spring 3.2.0](http://static.springsource.org/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.0.M1/api/org/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationUtils.html) (at least I haven't found in APIs upto spring 3.0)</strike> spring 3.1 (*thanks to Sebastien*) so you most likely have used spring 3.1 or higher for building your application and a version prior to 3.1 on tomcat. Investigate in that direction.

Comment: it's on spring 3.1 and i agree there should be different spring versions used since the class seems to be found.

Answer (score 1):

You'd better past the full stack with the causes, it would help (not much in this case but it's always better)

Since you get a NoSuchMethodError, it seems the AnnotationUtils class is found, but the method called getAnnotation may not be found.
So at runtime i think the wrong version of the class could be used.

You should check on your webapp folder which version of spring is deployed, and check that version have the "getAnnotation" method.

You can check there:
https://fisheye.springsource.org/browse/spring-framework/org.springframework.core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationUtils.java

Notice that it seems the classes have been reorganized on the master branch (are you using that???)

You should also perform a mvn dependency:tree and check the spring versions here, see if you don't have many different spring versions here, and if it's the case, use the dependency exclusion, or the dependency management tag of maven to specify exactly which version you want to use

Comment: for me, your comment helped. I performed mvn dependency:tree and found the problem in a dependency of a dependency.

Answer (score -1):

You haven't correctly deployed the Spring libraries to your instance of Tomcat.

Comment: I use maven to deploy my project(package tomcat:redeploy).Can you tell me how to do? thanks

Comment: run mvn dependencies:list and check whether you have clashing versions of spring, as Andreas_D suggested you might have above.  Is the scope of your spring dependencies correct, and not accidentally set to `provided`?

Comment: It is also possible that you have more than one spring libraries available and it's taking the wrong one..