# Bean initialization exception

Tags: java, spring

I am new to Spring. When I am running a process, I am getting this exception. Any pointers how to get over it ?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'odinConfigurer' defined in class path resource [CMA-dao.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.getAnnotation(Ljava/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;
```

Comment: You have some sort of classpath problem. Without a whole lot more detail about how you're configuring and launching your program, it's impossible to say.

Answer (score 0):

looks like

you are using

```
     public static <A extends Annotation> A getAnnotation(AnnotatedElement element,
                                             Class<A> annotationType)
```

but correct signature is

```
    public static <A extends Annotation> A getAnnotation(Method method,
                                             Class<A> annotationType)
```

see [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.getAnnotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496413/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-springframework-core-annotation-annotationutils)