# Spring Boot 1.5.3 NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.getResponseStatus()

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

I'm trying to update my Maven application to `Spring Boot 1.5.3` version and right now it's failed with a following exception:

```
2017-04-30 22:17:35 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost] - Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.getResponseStatus()Lorg/springframework/http/HttpStatus;
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:978)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:469)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:392)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:254)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:349)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.getResponseStatus()Lorg/springframework/http/HttpStatus;
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.setResponseStatus(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:128)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:98)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

How to fix it ?

**UPDATED**

this is my spring-web* classpath:

[image]

pom xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>example</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.source.version>1.8</java.source.version>
        <java.target.version>1.8</java.target.version>

        <jta.version>1.1</jta.version>
        <cdi-api.version>2.0-EDR1</cdi-api.version>
        <commons-lang3.version>3.4</commons-lang3.version>
        <commons-validator.version>1.5.0</commons-validator.version>
        <commons-io.version>2.4</commons-io.version>        
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        </dependency>       

        <!-- Spring boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>${cdi-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>${jta.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-validator.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-io.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jUnit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <modules>
        <module>domain</module>
        <module>api</module>
    </modules>

</project>
--------------------------------------------
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <artifactId>example</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>domain</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <neo4j.version>3.1.3</neo4j.version>
        <graphaware-framework-embedded.version>3.1.3.47</graphaware-framework-embedded.version>
        <neo4j-to-elasticsearch.version>3.1.3.45.7</neo4j-to-elasticsearch.version>

        <guava.version>19.0-rc1</guava.version>
        <owasp-java-html-sanitize.version>20160924.1</owasp-java-html-sanitize.version>
        <UserAgentUtils.version>1.20</UserAgentUtils.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- neo4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j-ogm.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-embedded-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j-ogm.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphaware.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphaware-framework-embedded</artifactId>
            <version>${graphaware-framework-embedded.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphaware.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-to-elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j-to-elasticsearch.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-social-twitter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>${guava.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.owasp-java-html-sanitizer</groupId>
            <artifactId>owasp-java-html-sanitizer</artifactId>
            <version>${owasp-java-html-sanitize.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>eu.bitwalker</groupId>
            <artifactId>UserAgentUtils</artifactId>
            <version>${UserAgentUtils.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>

----------------------------------------------------------

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <parent>
        <artifactId>example</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>api</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.source.version>1.8</java.source.version>
        <java.target.version>1.8</java.target.version>

        <!-- example -->
        <com.example.domain.version>0.0.1</com.example.domain.version>
        <!-- 3rd party -->
        <spring.social.google.version>1.0.0.RELEASE</spring.social.google.version>
        <spring-social-github.version>1.0.0.M4</spring-social-github.version>

        <javaee-web-api.version>7.0</javaee-web-api.version>
        <rest-assured.version>2.9.0</rest-assured.version>
        <jaxb-api.version>2.2.12</jaxb-api.version>

        <neo4j.version>3.1.3</neo4j.version>
        <graphaware-framework-embedded.version>3.1.3.47</graphaware-framework-embedded.version>
        <neo4j-to-elasticsearch.version>3.1.3.45.7</neo4j-to-elasticsearch.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- example -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>domain</artifactId>
            <version>${com.example.domain.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Neo4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-embedded-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j-ogm.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphaware.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphaware-framework-embedded</artifactId>
            <version>${graphaware-framework-embedded.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphaware.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-to-elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j-to-elasticsearch.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot Social Providers -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-social-facebook</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-social-linkedin</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Social Providers -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-google</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.social.google.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-github</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-social-github.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- default j2ee dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javaee-web-api.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>${rest-assured.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxb-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


</project>
```

**UPDATED**

This is the output with `-verbose:class`:

```
[Loaded org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod from file:/C:/Users/Alexander/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.3.8.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar]

[Loaded org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod$ConcurrentResultHandlerMethod from file:/C:/Users/Alexander/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.3.8.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar]

2017-05-01 10:49:43 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] INFO  o.s.s.o.p.endpoint.TokenEndpoint - Handling error: NestedServletException, Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.getResponseStatus()Lorg/springframework/http/HttpStatus;
```

Comment: It's impossible to say exactly how to fix it with the information provided, but the cause is that you have different versions of spring-web and spring-webmvc on the classpath. What is in your pom.xml?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have updated my question with sprin-web* dependency hierarchy

Comment: Can you share your actual pom.xml please rather than a screenshot of something from your IDE? Alternatively, run your app with `-verbose:class` to learn where the different versions are coming from

Comment: sure, added 3 pom xml files. parent/domain/api

Comment: For starters remove all `org.springframework` dependencies. Those are already pulled in by the different `starters` you are trying very hard to work around all those starters (either use them or don't). The same for those `spring-boot-*` dependencies and slf4j/logback. If you have a starter `spring-boot-security-starter` you don't need to include the individual dependencies again.

Comment: They look fine in terms of versions so something else is messing up the classpath. Did you run with `-verbose:class` to see where things are being loaded from?

Comment: Also, in order to exclude the Maven repository issue(I faced a few previously) - I have completely re-downloaded my local repository but unfortunately It didn't help this time.

Comment: Please remove all the messing dependencies and use starter pom's for defining your dependencies. It is recommended to use this approach given in this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39245732/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-springframework-core-env-configurableenviron/39246493#39246493

Comment: @PraveenKumarKrishnaiyer yeah.. I have to refactor my poms, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the reason of this issue:

the parent class `org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod` of `ServletInvocableHandlerMethod` was also loaded from `graphaware-framework-embedded`

I have moved

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

above the `graphaware-framework-embedded` dependency (so now `spring-boot-starter-web` is loading first) and the issue is gone.

Comment: I just gave you an upvote as I googled for exactly the same issue. Found your solution very quickly which saved me hours or days to find the problem and solve it myself. Thanks!

Comment: Would it not be a better idea to exclude on from graphaware?

Comment: I was the same error and your solution was very effective. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This error is because, in the spring-mvc jar version that you have in your project doesn't contain the **ServletInvocableHandlerMethod**. I added the below dependency and my code is working.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
     <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

OK in my instance seems that the problem was a conflict between different spring versions.  spring-boot 1.5.9.RELEASE was bringing in spring 4.3.13.RELEASE (especially spring-webmvc of that version) but I had this other spring dependencies explicitly versioned in my pom (or parent pom), effectively overriding the spring-boot version and causing a collision:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

result: boom!

See also [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.getAnnotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496413/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-springframework-core-annotation-annotationutils)

Another clue: in `mvn dependency:tree` underneath spring-boot it said:

```
 [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.4.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 4.3.13.RELEASE)
```

version managed means "version overridden from elsewhere" apparently.

Fix: bring them all to 4.3.4 or all to 4.3.13

Answer (score 0):

I saw your screenshot and it seems that you are working in Eclipse.
My problem was strictly related to Eclipse.

- **run maven (clean then install) outside of Eclipse**

  - if it passes. it means that the problem is likely introduced by Eclipse - see below.
  - if it does not pass - you need to fix your dependencies ...

    - consider stripping them until you get the stuff working; you will figure out quickly what is causing issue.
- **in Eclipse:**

  - close all unrelated projects
  - close referenced projects (e.g. use build from artifactory or something)
  - try running it again.

    - if you get pass - one of referenced projects might can be causing a problem by introducing conflicting dependencies; or some Eclipse-related issue (my case).
    - add/remove projects to see what is the impact on dependency hierarchy when you 
      add the other project.
    - if you still don't get pass: strip the stuff until you get
  - exclude dependencies from referenced project.