# Spring3 MVC+ Hibernate error

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm trying to make an application with Spring3 MVC and Hibernate, but something I'm doing wrong because every time I try to make a database query I have this error:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:63)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:687)
    com.ibex.pBaseSpring.repository.hibernate.HibernateUsuarioDAO.login(HibernateUsuarioDAO.java:25)
    com.ibex.pBaseSpring.service.impl.UsuarioManagerImpl.login(UsuarioManagerImpl.java:23)
    com.ibex.pBaseSpring.web.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:32)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:427)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:415)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:788)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:717)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

I tried all the solutions I found and I still get the same error, this is my code:

**app-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ibex.pBaseSpring.repository" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ibex.pBaseSpring.service" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ibex.pBaseSpring.web" />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>

    <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/spring/hibernate.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>${hibernate.connection.driver_class}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url">
            <value>${hibernate.connection.url}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <value>${hibernate.connection.username}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>${hibernate.connection.password}</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.ibex.pBaseSpring.domain" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**" />
</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>pBaseSpring</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>pBaseSpring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
       <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
       <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>pBaseSpring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**LoginController**

```
package com.ibex.pBaseSpring.web;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import com.ibex.pBaseSpring.domain.Usuario;
import com.ibex.pBaseSpring.service.UsuarioManager;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

    private UsuarioManager usuarioManager;

    @Inject
    public LoginController(UsuarioManager usuarioManager){
        this.usuarioManager = usuarioManager;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/inicio")
    public String inicio(){
        //comprobar que el usuario no esta registrado ya...
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/login")
    public String login(@RequestParam("login") String login, @RequestParam("pass") String pass){
        System.out.println(login + " - " + pass);
        Usuario usuario = usuarioManager.login(login, pass);
        return "main";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/logout")
    public String logout(){
        return "inicio";
    }
}
```

**UsuarioManager**

```
package com.ibex.pBaseSpring.service.impl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.ibex.pBaseSpring.domain.Usuario;
import com.ibex.pBaseSpring.repository.UsuarioDAO;
import com.ibex.pBaseSpring.service.UsuarioManager;
@Service
public class UsuarioManagerImpl implements UsuarioManager{

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioDAO usuarioDAO;
    public void setUsuarioDAO(UsuarioDAO usuarioDAO) {
        this.usuarioDAO = usuarioDAO;
    }
    public Usuario login(String login, String pass) {
        return usuarioDAO.login(login, pass);
    }
}
```

**HibernateUsuarioDAO**

```
package com.ibex.pBaseSpring.repository.hibernate;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.ibex.pBaseSpring.domain.Usuario;
import com.ibex.pBaseSpring.repository.UsuarioDAO;

@Repository
public class HibernateUsuarioDAO implements UsuarioDAO{

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public HibernateUsuarioDAO(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Usuario login(String login, String pass) {
        Criteria c = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Usuario.class);
        c.add(Restrictions.eq("login", login));
        c.add(Restrictions.eq("pass", pass));
        return (Usuario) c.uniqueResult();
    }

}
```

I'm a little desperate, thanks for the help. Bye!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not added `tx` in your bean. refere this bean tag

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
">
```

and then add this line in your app-config.xml :

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

Comment: When I put this I get this error:

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml]: Initialization of bean failed;`

Comment: `nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.getAnnotation(Ljava/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;`

Comment: make sure you added all jar files of spring of same version. I think you are having problem with jar files dependencies.

Comment: check this link also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164001/spring-transaction-manager-annotation-style-runtime-error

Comment: I don't know, because now the server will not find the RequestMapping

`WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/pBaseSpring/inicio] in DispatcherServlet with name 'pBaseSpring'`

Comment: change your servlet maping like this in web.xml : `<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>pBaseSpring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>`

Comment: I have solved it was my fault I commented <mvc:annotation-driven /> in app-config.xml. sorry

Answer (score 1):

You missed `<tx:annotation-driven />`, `@Transactional` won't work without it.